# Совпадение со строками, содержащими заглавные буквы, но не полностью состоящими из них

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Задача из книжки. Написать регулярку, которая проверяет соответствие строковой переменной правилу:

1. есть **хотя бы одна** буква в верхнем регистре
2. есть **хотя бы одна** буква в нижнем регистре
3. эти 2 символа идут подряд, порядок не имеет значения

Для простоты, считаем, что строки **не содержат** переводов строк.

Я написал что-то такое: `/[a-z]*[A-Z]+[a-z]*/` или `/[a-z]*[A-Z]+[a-z]+/`

Предлагается потестить на строках типа `"fred"`, `"Fred"` и `"frEd"`. Я нашел одно слово, с которым данный шаблон не совпадает, это `"freD"`. Как обобщить регулярку на все возможные строки?

Ответ в книге про перл еще хуже, чем мое решение.

Comment: "не состоящее полностью из них" значит, что в слове должна быть хотя бы одна строчная буква? или имеется ввиду, что в строке должен быть любой символ, кроме заглавной буквы и хотя бы одна заглавная буква?

Comment: И где искать просто что где то в переменной есть и маленькие и большие и надо ли выделять то что нашел. А то ведь можно забежать вперед проверить на маленькие потом на большие `(?=.*?[a-z]+).*?[A-Z]+`

Comment: так же интересует, каким образом должны обрабатываться много-строчные строки (уж простите за тавтологию)

Comment: Строки рассматриваются однострочные. Да, верно: в строке должна быть хотя бы одна строчная буква и хотя бы одна заглавная. Иначе строка отвергается.

Comment: @typemoon Значит приведенное мной в комментарии подходит

Comment: А еще: где-нибудь есть словарь, в котором дан перевод терминов типа capturing group, branch reset group и подобные? Читаю англоязычные мануалы и не могу подобрать русский эквивалент при переводе.

Comment: @Mike пока я делал демо, вы уже про это написали, тока немного по-другому :)

Comment: @splash58 Для выхватывания подходящих слов целиком я еще придумал `([a-z]+)?[A-Z]+(?(1)|[a-z]+)[A-Za-z]*` а от ваш ответ из за \b не захватит Fred6 потому как раздела слова не будет и он не найдет никакого совпадения

Comment: я как-то на буковки только рассчитывал. так что, там в любом месте цифра его собьет с толку. Но ваша регулярка не поймет совсем  цифру в середине слова Fr6ed

Comment: Ну это на случай если цифра т.к. она не входит в оговоренный набор должна разбить "слово"

Comment: не, я там по-русски буковку набил :) всё правильно. Ну можно поменять в моем выражении \b на не букву, кстати говоря

Comment: `\b[a-zA-Z]*([a-z][A-Z]|[A-Z][a-z])[a-zA-Z]*\b`

Answer (score 3):

```
/([a-z][A-Z])|([A-Z][a-z])/
```

Разве это не в точности соответствует поставленному условию?

```perl
foreach (qw/fred FRED fRed Fred freD 1234/) {
    if (/([a-z][A-Z])|([A-Z][a-z])/) {
        print "$_ - ok\n";
    } else {
        print "$_ - bad\n";
    }
}
```

вывод:

```
fred - bad
FRED - bad
fRed - ok
Fred - ok
freD - ok
1234 - bad
```

П.С. Круглые скобки в регулярке - необязательны, но я предпочитаю их ставить в такой ситуации.

Comment: интересно какой результат должен быть у `fREd`?

Comment: @Grundy 1) есть маленькая буква 2) есть большая 3) они идут подряд. Все условия соблюдены - ОК.

Comment: да, не проверил, думал он парами будет проверять :)

Comment: `1234Fred` ? `$%^Fr$&^` ?

Comment: @ReinRaus В условии не сказано, что строка должна состоять только из буквенных символов.

Comment: @ReinRaus Согласно приведенным условиям, обе строки - ОК.

Comment: Хз. Возможно. Я мотивируюсь тем, что `Задача из книжки`. Если допустить, что возможен весь набор символов, то задача действительно сводится к Вашему варианту решения и при этом задача полностью теряет всю обучающую нагрузку. В моем понимании данного вопроса должен остаться обучающий эффект, который состоит из комбинирования диапазонов заглавных и строчных символов. В остальном Вы правы. Строго следуя условиям задачи- Ваш ответ соответствует им.

Comment: @ReinRaus `/^[A-Za-z]*([A-Z][a-z]|[a-z][A-Z])[A-Za-z]*$/` - то же, для строки, состоящей только из букв.

Answer (score 2):

Если слово начинается с больших - ищем маленькую, если с маленьких - большую

```
\b([A-Z]+[a-z]|[a-z]+[A-Z])[A-Za-z]*\b
```

[демо](https://www.regex101.com/r/bY7uO7/3)

Comment: а не поделитесь, за что минусуете?

Comment: Хз. На текущий момент единственный правильный ответ )

Comment: ну ладно, может еще откликнется...

Answer (score 1):

Как насчет `[^A-Z]+[A-Z]+|[A-Z]+[^A-Z]+`?

Comment: Такая регулярка будет считать строками и наборы символов, содержащие цифры. Вряд ли это допустимо по условию задачи.

Comment: [^A-Z]+ Если я не ошибаюсь, строка обязана начинаться с какого-то символа, не являющегося заглавной буквой. Но тогда строка Fred не совпадет с шаблоном.

Comment: Вроде как соответствует условию задачи. "ищет строки, в которых есть заглавные буквы". В строке, насколько я понимаю, могут быть любые символы.

Comment: Fred, freD, fRed - совпадает. FRED, fred - нет.

Comment: тут, по большому счету, все зависит от того, могут ли по условию задачи встретится символы, отличные от `[a-zA-Z]`, и от того, как их нужно обрабатывать. туда же догонкой - вопрос про то, а нужно ли искать буквы, отличные от букв латинского алфавита?

Comment: В условиях нет ни слова о том, какие символы могут быть в строке

Answer (score 0):

Можно упростить и регулярку и само решение:

```
sub check_string {
 ($_[0]=~/([a-z]?[A-Z][a-z]?)/ and length $1 > 1) ? 1 : 0;
}

print check_string($_) for qw/ fREd fRed Fred FRED freD 88a9 /;
```